# How to make image circular in tableview in swift

Tags: ios, uiimageview, calayer

In the func `cellForRowAt`:

```
userCell.img.layer.cornerRadius = userCell.img.frame.size.width / 2.0
userCell.img.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
```

i tried this way but image is not in perfect circular shape.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

1. The size of the image view in `cellForRowAt` often is not the size it will be by the time. You want to respond to the resizing of the image view, best done by

   - subclassing `UIImageView`;
   - apply `cornerRadius` in the `layoutSubviews` method; and
   - specify this class as the “base class” for the image view in your cell.

   For example:

   ```
   @IBDesignable
   class RoundedImageView: UIImageView {
       override func layoutSubviews() {
           super.layoutSubviews()
           layer.cornerRadius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
           layer.borderWidth = 3
       }
   }
   ```
2. The above enjoys a certain simplicity, but only works if the resized image view is precisely square. If not, you’ll get a pill-shaped border.

   [image]

   You can alternatively implement a rendition that will apply a round mask within the `bounds` of the image view, and then adding the circular border as a separate sublayer, e.g.

   ```
   @IBDesignable
   class CircularImageView: UIImageView {
       @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 3 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

       private var borderLayer: CAShapeLayer?

       override func layoutSubviews() {
           super.layoutSubviews()
           let maskRadius = min(bounds.width, bounds.height) / 2
           let borderRadius = maskRadius - borderWidth / 2
           let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)

           let mask = CAShapeLayer()
           mask.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: maskRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath
           mask.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
           layer.mask = mask

           borderLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
           let border = CAShapeLayer()
           border.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: borderRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true).cgPath
           border.lineWidth = borderWidth
           border.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
           border.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
           layer.addSublayer(border)
           self.borderLayer = border
       }
   }
   ```

   Obviously, if your image view isn’t quite square, this will mask the circle in the center of the image view, but achieves the desired result even when the underlying image view isn’t quite square.

   [image]

Both of these approaches enjoy the virtue of getting your `cellForRowAt` method out of the business of configuring the details of the image view. And, needless to say, while the above screen snapshots are not in table views, the basic idea works wherever you have your image views (as long as you set the base class accordingly).